# Cartthrob Stripe Checkout API

Tags: checkout, stripe

I'm new to Cartthrob, what an amazing product. I'd like to incorporate Stripe's Checkout API as a way to have my client's checkout. It's beautiful, and very easy to use - but I can't figure out how to integrate the API into Cartthrob.

Information can be found here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Do you offer support for this?

Thanks,
-Nick

Answer (score 1):

CartThrob already has a Stripe Payment Gateway you will want to follow http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/payments/index.html to enable the Stripe gateway on your site.

You shouldn't need it but if you were interested in developing your own gateway you would want to follow their [Payment Gateway Plugin API](http://cartthrob.com/docs/developers/payment_gateways/index.html) guidelines.

Comment: +1 for using the built in payment gateway for Stripe. I was astonished how easy it was. Having a bit of experience with other payment systems I was suspicious that something was wrong. But no, it all worked perfectly immediately.